# Why my .net core Api not showing error message in production?

Tags: .net

I have classs librarry in produciton.

I have

```
   if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

}
```

I am getting
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I want to see the exception details.

Comment: Why do you want to enable to error details to be shown on the page in production? That's generally not reccomended. Instead, set up proper logging so that errors go somewhere useful to you: a file, APM software, Windows event logs etc.

Comment: I just want to learn

Comment: how did you set you 'environment'?

Comment: I have  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"

Comment: @qamar any luck ?

Comment: You just want to learn? Then learn to do it right: set up logging in your application. Production instances of applications should not provide full error details to users - they don't need to know the full error details, and it could potentially give an attacker information to use to exploit your app. Instead, show a nice friendly error page that says something along the lines of "Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred. Please contact support team" and log the details of the error to an appropriate place.

Comment: I know that man. I just need  to know what is the error I am getting

Comment: @qamar any luck